# How to select a line break with regular expressions

Tags: r, regex

I am working in R and trying to clean a file to remove the line breaks in inconvenient positions, namely all the spaces between tags

```
<sometext> ... \n .. </sometext>
```

for example

```
<TEXT>Purchased this as a cert pre owned for a great price. \n
Had only 10000 miles on it and jumped on it.</TEXT>
```

to become

```
<TEXT>Purchased this as a cert pre owned for a great price.Had only 10000 miles on it and jumped on it.</TEXT>
```

I am thinking on using an expression such as

```
(<[A-z]+>)(.+)(\n)(.+)(<\/[A-z]+>)
```

and then remove any matches in the 3rd group, but It must be something more "clever" to do.

Comment: "In UTF-8 mode, \R matches any Unicode newline character (not just CR)" https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to remove a single or a single chunk of consecutive line breaks only between two tags with optional whitespace round the line break(s).

Use a PCRE regex replacement:

```
x <- "<TEXT>Purchased this as a cert pre owned for a great price. \nHad only 10000 miles on it and jumped on it.</TEXT>"
gsub("(<TEXT>.*?)\\h*\\R+\\h*(.*?</TEXT>)", "\\1\\2", x, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] "<TEXT>Purchased this as a cert pre owned for a great price.Had only 10000 miles on it and jumped on it.</TEXT>"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kMrWc4/1) and an [R demo](https://ideone.com/cqb0EW).

**Details**

- `(<TEXT>.*?)`  - Group 1: `<TEXT>` and then any 0+ chars other than line break chars (as a `.` in a PCRE regex does not match line breaks) as few as possible, up to the first occurrence of the subsequent subpattersn
- `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces (greedy match)
- `\R+` - any 1 or more line break sequences (CR, LF or CRLF)
- `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces (greedy match)
- `(.*?</TEXT>)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than line break chars and `</TEXT>` string.

The `\1` inserts back the value in Group 1 and `\2` does the same with Group 2 value.

**If you want to replace multiple occurrences in between two strings** use Hack-R's `gsubfn` approach:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> x2 <- "<TEXT>Purchased this as a cert pre owned for a great price. \nHad only 10000 miles on it and jumped on it.  \r\nAnd another sentence.</TEXT>"
> gsubfn("(<TEXT>)(.*?)(</TEXT>)", function(g1,g2,g3) paste0(g1,gsub("\\h*\\R+\\h*", "", g2, perl=TRUE),g3), x2) 
[1] "<TEXT>Purchased this as a cert pre owned for a great price.Had only 10000 miles on it and jumped on it.And another sentence.</TEXT>"
```

The `(<TEXT>)(.*?)(</TEXT>)` pattern matches and captures into Group 1 `<TEXT>`, then captures into Group 2 any 0+ chars as few as possible (lazy match), and then captures into Group 3 `</TEXT>`. Then, in the callback inside `gsubfn`, you may remove all occurrences of `<spaces>*<line_break(s)><spaces>*` with `gsub("\\h*\\R+\\h*", "", g2, perl=TRUE)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution was very well explained

Answer (score 4):

I think you may be overcomplicating this, unless I'm misunderstanding something:

```
string <- "<TEXT>Purchased this as a cert pre owned for a great price.

Had only 10000 miles on it and jumped on it.</TEXT>"

string

[1] "<TEXT>Purchased this as a cert pre owned for a great price.\n\nHad only 10000 miles on it and jumped on it.</TEXT>"

gsub("\n"," ", string)


[1] <TEXT> Purchased this as a cert pre owned for a great price.  Had
only 10000 miles on it and jumped on it.</TEXT>
```

**Update**: Based on your comment you want to this only in between tag pairs. We can do this pretty easily with the `gsubfn` package:

```
string <- "Don't delete this newline 


<TEXT>Purchased this as a cert pre owned for a great price.
Had only 10000 miles on it and jumped on it.</TEXT>"

string

gsub("\n"," ", string)


library(gsubfn)
gsub("\n", " ", strapplyc(string, ">(.*?)</", simplify = c))
```

Where the result is:

```
[1] "Purchased this as a cert pre owned for a great price. Had only 10000 miles on it and jumped on it."
```

The text not in between tags is not matched and thus not effected by the `gsub`.

Depending on your needs you might also want something like this:

```
sub("<(.*?)>(.*?)</(.*?)>",gsub("\n", " ", strapplyc(string, ">(.*?)</", simplify = c)),string)

[1] "Don't delete this newline\n Purchased this as a cert pre owned for a great price. Had only 10000 miles on it and jumped on it."
```

Comment: I might not have explained myself properly.

I have a document that has hundreds of strings like that and is not XML valid. 99% of times there are no line breaks between lines so most of the text can be parsed using scan(), however, I want to make it robust to the exceptions.

Using gsub("\n"," ", string) will delete all line breaks, including the needed ones.

Comment: @comendeiro Are you saying that you only want to delete the newline characters if they are in between <TEXT> tags? Or what is the situation that determines whether or not you want to delete the newline character?

Comment: That's correct @Hack-R. Only if they are between ANY kind of tag <TEXT></TEXT> or <ipsum></ipsum>

Comment: Thank you very much. What do you reckon is faster, this solution or the one below? both work for me

Comment: @comendeiro Great, glad to hear they both work for you. I'd have to run microbenchmark to find out which is faster. If you'd like me to do that I can, but I have to eat lunch first because my pizza just finished heating up.

Comment: No worries, thank you very much. I only asked in case you've already done a similar exercise in the past. Cheers!